# PFLoginViewController Jumbled on iPhone 4S Screen

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cgrectmake, pfloginviewcontroller

I have subclassed `PFLoginViewController` in my app with the code below.  On a 5S or 6 device, everything looks as it should.  However, on a 4S or lower device, some buttons are too high, some are too low, so much that you can't even see the Sign Up button.  Could someone check out my framing and see if there's a way I could do it better to make it all fit across all devices?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon76x76@2x.png" ]];
    self.logInView.logo = logoView; // logo can be any UIView
    self.fieldsBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginFieldBG.png"]];
    UITextView *iprayed = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 40)];
    iprayed.text = @"iPrayed 4 U";
    iprayed.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    iprayed.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    iprayed.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:25];
    iprayed.font = cellFont;
    [self.logInView addSubview:iprayed];
    [self.logInView insertSubview:self.fieldsBackground atIndex:1];
}
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CALayer * l = [self.logInView.logo layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:40];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

    // Set frame for elements
    [self.logInView.dismissButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 87.5f, 45.5f)];
    [self.logInView.logo setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 40, 80, 80)];
    [self.logInView.facebookButton setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 400.0f, 120.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.logInView.twitterButton setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f+130.0f, 400.0f, 120.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.logInView.signUpButton setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 490.0f, 250.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.logInView.usernameField setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 175.0f, 250.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.logInView.passwordField setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 225.0f, 250.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.fieldsBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 175.0f, 250.0f, 100.0f)];
    [self.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 35.0f, 40.0f)];
}
```

iPhone 5S:
[image]

iPhone 4S:
[image]

Comment: you have to do relative layout, y co-ordinate of sign up button defined by you is 490.0f while iPhone 4s height is 480.0f. This is the issue.

Comment: @rishi, so how would I go about fixing it?  As I said, everything is shifted around too much, not just the sign up button.

Comment: @rishi Just got pictures adding showing differences.

Comment: this is what i told you, when the screen size is 480.0f then defining origin y co-ordinate as 490.0f will not work. So you have to define some relative layout based on height.

Comment: What you could do is just setup your frames like a chain... So the origin of the login button is dependent of the origin + height of the password field and so on